# Usage of Location directive in apache2.2

Tags: apache, location, directive

I am trying for the below. tried many ways but nothing seems to be working, if anyone is having any idea please help.

```
<Location /MyRoot>
# '/MyRoot' Should only be allowed, and NONE of its sub should be allowed
# Requests will be redirected to weblogic
</Location>
<Location /MyRoot/MySub1>
# '/MyRoot/MySub1' Should be allowed, and all its sub domains should be allowed
# Requests will be redirected to weblogic
</Location>
<Location /MyRoot/MySub2>
# '/MyRoot/MySub1' Should be allowed, and all its sub domains should be allowed
# Requests will be redirected to weblogic
</Location>
```

What I am expecting is below

```
http://host:port/MyRoot/ --- Should be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/MySub1 --- Should be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/MySub2 --- Should be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/MySub1/MySubSub1 --- Should be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/MySub1/MySubSub2 --- Should be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/MySub2/MySubSub1 --- Should be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/MySub2/MySubSub2 --- Should be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/MySub1/MySubSub1 --- Should be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/MySub1/MySubSub2 --- Should be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/ABC --- Should NOT be accessible
http://host:port/MyRoot/XYZ/LKJ --- Should NOT be accessible
```

and there could be many folders under MyRoot which I want them to be INaccessible except(MySub1 & MuS)

Can anyone please advice on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

At least as I know at this time, this is not possible just with the `.htaccess` on root directory.

You have to create the `.htaccess` on `/MyRoot/` with this code:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

To avoid root directory listing from external users. Then, inside `/MyRoot/MySub1/MySubSub1`, `/MyRoot/MySub1/MySubSub2`, `/MyRoot/MySub2/MySubSub1`, `/MyRoot/MySub2/MySubSub2` and consecutively you have to create an `.htaccess` with this:

```
Allow from all
```

This should solve your question, in some ways. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I dont think i can really use .htaccess because these folders are served from AppServer and at Apache I dont have access to these folders. so I dont think I can use 'Deny from all'